# Pandas read_csv not reading the file (while-loop)

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I am trying to read several (~30) csv-sheets i have stored on my PC.

```
i=2
Liste1 = []
Liste2 = []
x = 0
while i < 32:
    string = str(i)
    if i < 10:
        try:

            Name = 'D:\\FTPDaten\\2020\\Alle\\2020010'+string+'.csv'
            Tabelle = pd.read_csv(Name, sep=';', decimal=",", header=0, usecols=[7, 20])
            Tabelle.columns = ['AC', 'DC']

            neueTabelle1 = Tabelle['AC']
            neueTabelle = Tabelle['DC']
            Schleifenlaenge = len(neueTabelle)
            j = 0
            del(Tabelle)
            while j < Schleifenlaenge:

                Datenwert1 = neueTabelle.iloc[j]
                Datenwert2 = neueTabelle1.iloc[j]
                Liste1.append(Datenwert1)
                Liste2.append(Datenwert2)
                j = j + 1
        except FileNotFoundError:
            i=i+1


    elif i >= 10 and i < 32:
        try:
            Name = 'D:\\FTPDaten\\2020\\Alle\\202001' + string + '.csv'
            Tabelle = pd.read_csv(Name, sep=';', decimal=",", header=0, usecols=[7, 20])
            Tabelle.columns = ['AC', 'DC']

            neueTabelle1 = Tabelle['AC']
            neueTabelle = Tabelle['DC']
            Schleifenlaenge = len(neueTabelle)
            j = 0
            
            while j < Schleifenlaenge:
                Datenwert1 = neueTabelle1.iloc[j]
                Datenwert2 = neueTabelle.iloc[j]
                Liste1.append(Datenwert1)
                Liste2.append(Datenwert2)
                j = j + 1
        except FileNotFoundError:
            i = i+1
    i = i + 1
```

When the while-loop is running for the first time everything works fine. When it comes into the first iteration, the read_csv does not read the file like it did before. I would expect to get a DataFrame where the 7th and 20th column is stored. But i do get a DataFrame with no content at all - just the header.
I tried a lot, but certainly i can´t fix it.

Comment: well 1 thing I notice is you only increment `i` if has an exception, not if it's successful.

Comment: Sorry i did not post the full code, but later on i did the increment of i. i updated it in the question itself.

Comment: ok. post the full code then here

Comment: is it possible to email me just a few of the csv files? It's toigh to figure out whats happening witout seeing whats being read in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with how it was reading in the `';'` in the other files (except the first one). If you open them in excel, you might be able to see what I'm talking about. So what you'll need to do is skip those rows at the beginning of the file.

```
import pandas as pd

Liste1 = []
Liste2 = []

for i in range(2,32):
    skipRows = 7
    if i != 2:
        skipRows += 1
    if i < 10:
        try:
            Name = 'D:\\FTPDaten\\2020\\Alle\\2020010{string}.csv'.format(string=i)
            Tabelle = pd.read_csv(Name, sep=';', decimal=",", header=0, usecols=[7, 20], skiprows=skipRows)
            Tabelle.columns = ['AC', 'DC']
 
            if i < 10:
                Datenwert1 = list(Tabelle['DC'])
                Datenwert2 = list(Tabelle['AC'])
            elif i >= 10 and i < 32:
                Datenwert1 = list(Tabelle['AC'])
                Datenwert2 = list(Tabelle['DC'])
                
            Liste1 += Datenwert1
            Liste2 += Datenwert2
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print(e)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':Datenwert1,   #<-- change 'col1', 'col2' to whatever you want to name them
                   'col2':Datenwert2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new dataframe here instead of iterate over the existing one

```
cols = ['AC', 'DC']
new_Tabelle = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
new_Tabelle['AC']=Tabelle['AC']
new_Tabelle['DC']=Tabelle['DC']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 30 semi-colon delimited files.  However this can be so easily simplified to only pick up files that exist and match a pattern using `glob`

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import random

for i in range(30):
    with open(f"2020010_os_{i}.csv", "w") as fp: fp.write(f"id;val\n{i};{random.randint(10,20)}\n")
        
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fn, sep=";") for fn in Path().cwd().glob("2020010*.csv")])
```